# No global monopoles in QCD

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, symmetry-breaking, weak-interaction, magnetic-monopoles, skyrmion

If a global symmetry gets both spontaneously and explicitly broken, the explicit symmetry breaking pattern is crucial for understanding the formation of *topological defects*.

For example, in the axion solution to the strong CP problem, the explicit breaking of the Peccei-Quinn (PQ) symmetry due to non-perturbative effects, $U(1)_{\rm PQ}\rightarrow Z_N$, leads to the formation of *domain walls*. Independently, the spontaneous breaking of $U(1)_{\rm PQ}$ by the vacuum expectation value of the axion field yields *cosmic strings*.

In QCD, the flavor $SU(3)\times SU(3)$ symmetry gets explicitly broken down to $U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1)$ by the non-zero quark masses $m_u\neq m_d\neq m_s$. Independently, the quark condensate spontaneously breaks $SU(3)\times SU(3)\rightarrow SU(3)$, leading to the formation of *skyrmions*.

Now my question is: why doesn't the explicit symmetry breaking in QCD lead to the formation of global *monopoles*? Is that because the $U(1)\times U(1)\times U(1)$ is further broken by weak effects?

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294023/2451